# Regex replace to map paginated URLs to a new format

Tags: regex, url, web-crawler, regexp-replace

I'm using a web crawler tool to compare two different website crawls before and after migration and need to map paginated URLs that have changed format.

e.g

Old: `https://example.com/page/2/` OR: `https://example.com/directory/page/16/`

New: `https://example.com/?page=2` OR: `https://example.com/directory/?page=16`

The tool has a regex replace feature for URL maping,

[image]

However, I cannot get the regex correct and the end result has an extra forward slash at the end:

`https://example.com/?page=2/`

What is the correct regex here to get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `/page/([0-9]+)/`

Replace: `/?page=$1`